# Given an approximation of the minimum of f using gradient descent, can I prove I am near a local min?

Tags: optimization, proof-writing

Do we really know that we are near a local min when using gradient descent or [Nelder-Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) method?

Suppose that

- I have a function $f$ that is analytic on the open ball $B = B(x, r)\subset R^n$,
- if the coordinates of $x$ are rational, then $f(x)$ and $\nabla f(x)$ are rational,
- I can evaluate $f$ and $\nabla f$ in one millisecond for any point $x$ in $B$ where the coordinates of $x$ are rational and the numerators and denominators have less than 20 digits,
- I use the Nelder-Mead method to get the vector $y$ where $f(y)$ seems to be a good approximation of the minimum of $f$ on $B(x,r)$, and
- $\|y-x\| < r/10$.

Is there a way that I can prove that $f$ achieves a local minimum on the interior of $B(x,r)$?  (In other words, can I prove that there exists a $z$ in the open ball $B(x,r)$ such that $f(z) \leq f(w)$ for all $w\in B(x,r)$?)

I can only think of two approaches:

1. Try to prove there exist positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ where $a/b<r/4$, $\| \nabla f(y) \|<a$, and $$\min_{\|v\|=1} v^T H(w)v>b$$ for all $w\in B(x,r)$ (where $H$ is the Hessian),
2. Enclose $y$ in a polytope and then prove there exists an $a$ such thatn  $f(y)<a<f(w)$ for all $w$ on the boundary of the polytope.

Are there any other commonly used methods to prove that your numerical optimization method is actually near a local min?  If we run gradient descent on a neural net, do we ever really know that we are near a local min?

edit: Changed $a/b<r/2$ to $a/b<r/4$ in approach 1.

edit2: Put a limit on the number of digits when doing fast numerical evaluation of $f(x)$ for rational $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  In the worst case, you can construct a function $g$ that has identical value (and first derivative, second derivative, etc.) on the same points where you evaluated $f$, but is arbitrarily nasty.  For instance, $g$ can have a narrow canyon/gully leading away from $y$ that allows water to flow downhill from $y$ towards some other local minimum outside of $B(x,r)$, but is so narrow that it misses all of the points where you evaluated $f$.  Especially in high dimensions, that gully can account for an extremely tiny fraction of the volume of $B(x,r)$, so if you're unlucky it can be very hard to find.

In general, usually these numerical methods are used in domains where it's not going to be feasible to get any kind of guarantees, or where the guarantees that are achievable are usually not terribly helpful in practice.  So I suggest shifting your mindset towards one that accepts that there aren't any ironclad guarantees.  Alternatively, if you truly need guarantees, you probably will need to make use of stronger properties of $f$ or additional structure it possesses.

Comment: Thanks!  I really like your answer because it's obvious after you read it.  In my particular case, my functions are rational $f_n:R^n\rightarrow R$, $f_n(x) = p_n(x)/q_n(x)$ where $p_n$ and $q_n$ are polynomials of degree $n$ with approximately $2^n$ terms and small integer coefficients. Both the $p_n$ and $q_n$ are strictly positive over the domain. (There are tricks for $O(n^2)$ evaluation of $f$ in my case.)  Bounding the derivative is hard.  Bounding the Hessian is harder.